# How to train image classifications in tensorflow for grayscale images using flow_from_directory?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, grayscale

I am training a CNN model to classify grayscale images into 6 classes. While my code is working well on RGB images, it gives error when I apply it on grayscale images. Here is part of the code:

```
input_shape=(256, 256,1) # assign "1" to the last channel to account for grayscale.

target_size = (256, 256) # To use it in the flow_from_directory package


model_name='Test1'
model_filename = (model_name+'.hdf5') 

optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
loss=['categorical_crossentropy']
metrics = ['accuracy']


## Here is the model: 

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(6)) # To account for 6 classes
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()



train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)


vaidation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()



train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,  # points to the folder containing all training images
        target_size=target_size, 
        color_mode='grayscale', # to specify the grayscale
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode='categorical',
        interpolation='nearest') 


validation_generator = vaidation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_path,  # points to the folder containing all validation images
        target_size=target_size,
        color_mode='grayscale', # to specify the grayscale
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode='categorical',
        interpolation='nearest')


model.compile(optimizer, loss , metrics)

model_checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint((model_path+model_filename), monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.summary()


history = model.fit(
     train_generator,
     steps_per_epoch = num_of_train_img_raw//batch_size,
     epochs = epochs, 
     validation_data = validation_generator,
     validation_steps = num_of_val_img_raw//batch_size,
     callbacks=[model_checkpoint],
     use_multiprocessing = False)
```

Here is the error I receive:

"input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 1 vs 3"

Then the IDE kernel freezes!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is wasteful/slower but why not just convert the greyscale images into RGB? Unless you need superior performance or really want to update the model both of which will take time to do.

Use [grayscale_to_rgb](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/grayscale_to_rgb) (already built into tensorflow).

Comment: Thanks @Steven. If I want to convert the grayscale to rgb, where do I need to implement it in the code?

I am not sure whether converting it to rgb is the very right way, since color transformation itself may add confusion to distinguish between classes. I thought changing the code to be compatible with grayscale should not need much effort!

Comment: Also, the code works well if I remove the conv2D layers and only use FCN, but the number of trainable parameters will go very high and the accuracy I get is near 0.

Comment: It would go in the very beginning of your model since you want it to convert it before processing.  Right before the first conv. You'd also have to change the input shape to be (x, y, 3).

Comment: Also going from greyscale to RGB doesn't add any new information so it isn't "confusing." Unless I misunderstood something about your claim.  Both greyscale and RBG converted image from that greyscale will both render the same i.e. look the same.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Steven. Do you know of a way to make the code compatible with grayscale images?

Comment: I think you need to change this model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape)) to model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, data_format=None)). Otherwise it defaults to the image_data_format value found in your Keras config file at ~/.keras/keras.json. If you never set it, then it will be channels_last.

Comment: Thanks much @Steven. I will give these a try, and post the results here.